# Dynamic column name when uniting columns in R

Tags: r

I am uniting columns with matching suffixes inside a for loop. When I try to include a new column name for the united columns, it will only take the literal characters. Is there a way to make unite use the object's value?

```
for (i in length(names(df))){
  first_label = str_split_fixed(names(df)[i-1], "_", n=2)[2]
  second_label = str_split_fixed(names(df)[i], "_", n=2)[2]
  if (second_label == first_label){
    print("TRUE")
    unite_df <- unite(unite_df, first_label, names(df)[i], names(df)[i-1], sep="_" )
  }
}
```

The code does not have any errors, but the output only changes one column and the new name is "first_label" and I would like the column name to be the suffix.

Ex.
Current Data Frame:

Baseball_hat, Basketball_hat, Baseball_ball, Basketball_ball

10, 15, 11, 14

...

Desired Data Frame:

hat, ball

10_15, 11_14

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` syntax would be to `gather` into 'long' format, then `separate` the column names ('key') column into two, `spread` into 'wide' format, and `summarise` each column by `paste`ing the elements together

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c("key1", "key2")) %>% 
  spread(key2, value) %>% 
  summarise_at(-1, str_c, collapse="_")
#   ball   hat
#1 11_14 10_15
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Baseball_hat = 10L, Basketball_hat = 15L, Baseball_ball = 11L, 
    Basketball_ball = 14L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```